# FMDB: NULL Values Are Retrieved as Empty Strings

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, fmdb

I'm retrieving a customer record with FMDB and Swift using the (simplified) function below. When the optional value in the `title` column is `NULL`the title member of the returned customer object is an empty string rather than `nil`, which is misleading. **Can this be re-written such that `NULL` values are retrieved as `nil`?** -- Ideally without testing for empty strings and setting `nil` explicitly (also wrong if the value is in fact an empty string)?

```
func getCustomerById(id: NSUUID) -> Customer? {

    let db = FMDatabase(path: dbPath as String)
    if db.open() {
        let queryStatement = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE id = ?"
        let result = db.executeQuery(queryStatement, withArgumentsInArray: [id.UUIDString])

        while result.next() {
            var customer = Customer();
            customer.id = NSUUID(UUIDString: result.stringForColumn("customerId"))
            customer.firstName = result.stringForColumn("firstName")
            customer.lastName = result.stringForColumn("lastName")
            customer.title = result.stringForColumn("title")
            return customer
        }
    }
    else {
        println("Error: \(db.lastErrorMessage())")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: From the [source code](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/src/fmdb/FMResultSet.m#L273) I would assume that a NULL value *is* returned as `nil`.

Comment: I thought I checked by inspecting the database. Checked again - and you are right. And I'm embarrassed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NULL` values are returned as `nil`:

```
db.executeUpdate("create table foo (bar text)", withArgumentsInArray: nil)
db.executeUpdate("insert into foo (bar) values (?)", withArgumentsInArray: ["baz"])
db.executeUpdate("insert into foo (bar) values (?)", withArgumentsInArray: [NSNull()])

if let rs = db.executeQuery("select * from foo", withArgumentsInArray: nil) {
    while rs.next() {
        if let string = rs.stringForColumn("bar") {
            println("bar = \(string)")
        } else {
            println("bar is null")
        }
    }
}
```

That outputs:

> bar = baz
> bar is null

You might want to double check how the values were inserted. Specifically, were empty values added using `NSNull`? Or perhaps open the database in an external tool and verify that the columns are really `NULL` like you expected.

Comment: You are right, and new records are indeed inserted that way. I must have been looking at some older data that was added incorrectly. Thanks for explaining it here. I'll leave the question as your answer may me of use for others.